# How to execute a https GET request from java

Tags: java, https, get

I wrote a Java client which executes `http` GET requests without any problem. 
Now I want to modify this client in order to execute `https` GET requests.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

private String executeGet(final String url, String proxy, int port)
        throws IOException, RequestUnsuccesfulException, InvalidParameterException {

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;
    String ret = "";
    RequestConfig config;

    try {                       
        String hostname = extractHostname(url);
        logger.info("Hostname {}", hostname);

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(hostname, 80, null);

        HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxy, port, "http");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD));

        httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();         
        config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(myProxy).build();


        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setConfig(config);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);

        ...
```

I was expecting an easy modification like using `HttpsGet` instead of `HttpGet` but no, there is no `HttpsGet` class available.

What is the easiest way to modify this method in order to handle `https` GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a solution which looks easier that what has been posted here

```
private String executeGet(final String https_url, final String proxyName, final int port) {
    String ret = "";

    URL url;
    try {

        HttpsURLConnection con;
        url = new URL(https_url);

        if (proxyName.isEmpty()) {  
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } else {                
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyName, port));
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return (new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
                    }
                };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
        }

        ret = getContent(con);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify getContent method is of which class as I was getting error.

Comment: URL.getContent() is a shortcut for openConnection().getContent() so we need to look at the documentation for URLConnection.getContent()

Comment: it's smart to paste fully working snippet, not some code without imports.

Answer (score 3):

this is my quick and dirty https client in Java, that ignores invalid certificates and authenticates using BASIC

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

    public static HttpsURLConnection getConnection(boolean ignoreInvalidCertificate, String user, String pass, HttpRequestMethod httpRequestMethod, URL url) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        if (ignoreInvalidCertificate){
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new InvalidCertificateTrustManager() }, null);  
        }       
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        String authStr = user+":"+pass;
        String authEncoded = Base64.encodeBytes(authStr.getBytes());

        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);     

        if (ignoreInvalidCertificate){
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(new InvalidCertificateHostVerifier());
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

--

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class InvalidCertificateHostVerifier implements HostnameVerifier{
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String paramString, SSLSession paramSSLSession) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

--

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 * ignore invalid Https certificate from OPAM
 * <p>see http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/avoiding-sunsecurityvalidatorvalidatore.html
 */
public class InvalidCertificateTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString) throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString) throws CertificateException {
    }
}
```

maybe it's something you can start with.

of course, since you have the connection, you can retrieve the response contents using

```
InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

this does as a destructive code (i think)`import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

```
public static HttpsURLConnection getConnection(boolean ignoreInvalidCertificate, String user, String pass, HttpRequestMethod httpRequestMethod, URL url) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    if (ignoreInvalidCertificate){
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new InvalidCertificateTrustManager() }, null);  
    }       
    SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
```

`